# Only parameterless constructors and initializers for Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am getting this error,

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities.

Upon researching , this seems like a common problem with many answers. Except I cannot reverse engineer a lot of the answers so as I can solve this myself.

I realize the answer is in the error, but I can't see what needs to use parameterless constructors? Or for that matter in this example, I don't even know where the parameter even is???

This LINQ query giving me trouble:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Employee> ReturnEmployeesInSection(string section)
{
    using (StaffShiftManagerEntities dataBaseEntities = new  StaffShiftManagerEntities())
    {
          return new ObservableCollection<Employee>(dataBaseEntities.Staff_Data_TBL
             .Where(p => p.Section_Data == section && p.Staff_Bool == true)
             .Select(staff => new Employee(staff.Staff_No ?? -1,
                staff.Staff_Name_First, staff.Staff_Name_Second))
             .ToList()
             .GroupBy(staff => staff.Key)
             .Select(staff => staff.First())
             .OrderBy(staff => staff.Key)
             .ToList());
    }
}
```

And the `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName;

    public Employee(int key, string first = null, string second = null)
    {
        Key = key;
        FirstName = first;
        SecondName = second;
    }
}
```

And this is the class that Entity framework auto generated:

```
public partial class Staff_Data_TBL
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image_Col { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Staff_No { get; set; }
    public string Staff_Name_First { get; set; }
    public string Staff_Name_Second { get; set; }
    public string Section_Data { get; set; }
    public string Lic_Data { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Start_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> End_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Night_1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Night_2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Lunch_Data { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Unples_Data { get; set; }
    public string Staff_Part { get; set; }
    public bool Staff_Kaizen { get; set; }
    public int StaffKaizenPercentage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Staff_Bool { get; set; }
    public string Group_Section_Data { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Please excuse the naming conventions, I am in the process of changing everything to more standard naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create public parameterless constructor for `Employee` class.

```
public Employee() {}
```

Use object initializer instead of constructor with parameters:

```
     dataBaseEntities.Staff_Data_TBL
         .Where(s => s.Section_Data == section && s.Staff_Bool == true)
         .GroupBy(s => s.Staff_No) // Important, see notes below
         .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
         .OrderBy(s => s.Staff_No)
         .Select(s => new Employee {
            Key = s.Staff_No ?? -1,
            FirstName = s.Staff_Name_First,
            LastName = s.Staff_Name_Second
          })
         .ToList()
```

**NOTE**: As you can see I moved grouping and sorting prior to results projection. Thus you will do all job on server side instead of loading table data into memory.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks so much, I have been at this for so long.

Comment: @KyloRen use `ToList()` carefully it should be the last thing you use in query. Otherwise you will load all data before filtering out what you don't need.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, you have helped me understand an issue that has I have been at for I can't remember how long (Especiallt with you last note). I will definitely take that advice on the `ToList()`. Amazing stuff, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName;

    public Employee(int key, string first = null, string second = null)
    {
        Key = key;
        FirstName = first;
        SecondName = second;
    }
}
```

to

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(){} //Constructor with no parameters that needs to be added

    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => FirstName + " " + SecondName;

    public Employee(int key, string first = null, string second = null)
    {
        Key = key;
        FirstName = first;
        SecondName = second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately  I still get the same error with this.